# How to manage the timing to merge features that are supposed to ship at different timing

Tags: git, agile, scrum

We basically follow this for software development. I'd like to know if there is a good practice for a managing branch rule to release at different timing.
https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Assume that there are feature/1 and feature/2 branches. Feature 1 will be in production at the end of the current sprint and feature 2 is supposed to be in production after the next sprint. However, we are working on both of the features right now, and feature 2 is possibly completed in the current sprint. My concern is that feature 2 will possibly be merged to the develop branch if we finish it in the current sprint and then it will be shipped to production. Now we merge a pull request after approval so it might happen. Is there any good way to handle this?

Answer (score 4):

Typically you handle this using a feature flag system.  The code for a new feature is added with a feature flag, and it can be merged at any time.  However, the code is only turned on in production if the feature is enabled.  You can decide to turn on the features at build time or using a configuration file shipped with the product, or in some other way entirely.

This decouples development of the feature from release to production.  For example, if the documentation for a feature is held up, that feature may be delayed slightly from production, but the code can have already been merged.

Comment: I searched for some information about how to use feature flags. Some blogs say this is a code-based technique like an if-else statement. Is there any way to handle this with an application? We use Bitbucket and JIRA by the way.

Comment: It is a code-based technique that essentially involves an if-else statement, and it is the standard best practice.  There are frameworks for implementing it, but it will require integration with your code.  And no, there is no tool that will automate integrating it into your code.

Comment: Steps 1-10: Don't use bitbucket for source control. As far as @bk2204's answer goes, that is a perfectly valid solution. The issue is that, years down the road, one can wind up with tons of #if VERSION > X.Y.Z ... #endif blocks all over the place. If you follow this approach, you need to clean those up as you move forward.